# Angular/Java Clicking Register button gives POST 403 Forbidden error Error: Uncaught (in promise): AxiosError: Request failed with status code 403

Tags: angular, spring-boot, authentication, axios, http-status-code-403

I am doing a project and I am trying to integrate Login/Register into my Angular/Java Springboot application with JWT authentication.

I have been following this youtube tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YUqi1IjLX8I&t=3s
I had to tweak the code to integrate into my current project.
I have been doing it till 44:22 where he gets 200 code while I have been getting 403 error code.
Now I am stuck and have been searching for answers to no avail. Hopefully someone can help me solve this problem?

The following is the error that I am getting

```
POST http://localhost:8080/register 403 (Forbidden)
scheduleTask @ zone.js:2645
scheduleTask @ zone.js:389
onScheduleTask @ core.mjs:10752
scheduleTask @ zone.js:382
onScheduleTask @ zone.js:279
scheduleTask @ zone.js:382
scheduleTask @ zone.js:216
scheduleMacroTask @ zone.js:239
scheduleMacroTaskWithCurrentZone @ zone.js:672
(anonymous) @ zone.js:2678
proto.<computed> @ zone.js:962
dispatchXhrRequest @ xhr.js:258
ZoneAwarePromise @ zone.js:1411
xhr @ xhr.js:49
dispatchRequest @ dispatchRequest.js:51
_request @ Axios.js:170
(anonymous) @ Axios.js:40
asyncGeneratorStep @ asyncToGenerator.js:3
_next @ asyncToGenerator.js:22
(anonymous) @ asyncToGenerator.js:27
ZoneAwarePromise @ zone.js:1411
(anonymous) @ asyncToGenerator.js:19
request @ Axios.js:59
wrap @ bind.js:5
request @ axios.service.ts:16
onRegister @ content.component.ts:25
ContentComponent_Template_app_login_form_onSubmitRegisterEvent_3_listener @ content.component.html:5
executeListenerWithErrorHandling @ core.mjs:16795
wrapListenerIn_markDirtyAndPreventDefault @ core.mjs:16828
next @ Subscriber.js:91
_next @ Subscriber.js:60
next @ Subscriber.js:31
(anonymous) @ Subject.js:34
errorContext @ errorContext.js:19
next @ Subject.js:27
emit @ core.mjs:10670
onSubmitRegister @ login-form.component.ts:33
LoginFormComponent_Template_form_ngSubmit_24_listener @ login-form.component.html:31
executeListenerWithErrorHandling @ core.mjs:16795
wrapListenerIn_markDirtyAndPreventDefault @ core.mjs:16828
next @ Subscriber.js:91
_next @ Subscriber.js:60
next @ Subscriber.js:31
(anonymous) @ Subject.js:34
errorContext @ errorContext.js:19
next @ Subject.js:27
emit @ core.mjs:10670
onSubmit @ forms.mjs:3474
NgForm_submit_HostBindingHandler @ forms.mjs:3506
executeListenerWithErrorHandling @ core.mjs:16795
wrapListenerIn_markDirtyAndPreventDefault @ core.mjs:16828
(anonymous) @ platform-browser.mjs:665
invokeTask @ zone.js:402
(anonymous) @ core.mjs:10757
onInvokeTask @ core.mjs:10757
invokeTask @ zone.js:401
onInvokeTask @ core.mjs:11070
invokeTask @ zone.js:401
runTask @ zone.js:173
invokeTask @ zone.js:483
invokeTask @ zone.js:1631
globalCallback @ zone.js:1662
globalZoneAwareCallback @ zone.js:1695
Show 58 more frames
Show less
axios.service.ts:16  ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): AxiosError: Request failed with status code 403
AxiosError: Request failed with status code 403
    at settle (settle.js:19:12)
    at XMLHttpRequest.onloadend [as __zone_symbol__ON_PROPERTYloadend] (xhr.js:111:13)
    at XMLHttpRequest.wrapFn (zone.js:755:39)
    at _ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:402:31)
    at core.mjs:10757:55
    at AsyncStackTaggingZoneSpec.onInvokeTask (core.mjs:10757:36)
    at _ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:401:60)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.mjs:11070:33)
    at _ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:401:60)
    at Zone.runTask (zone.js:173:47)
    at Axios.js:45:41
    at Generator.throw (<anonymous>)
    at asyncGeneratorStep (asyncToGenerator.js:3:1)
    at _throw (asyncToGenerator.js:25:1)
    at _ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:368:26)
    at Object.onInvoke (core.mjs:11083:33)
    at _ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:367:52)
    at Zone.run (zone.js:129:43)
    at zone.js:1257:36
    at _ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:402:31)
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:1193:31)
    at zone.js:1100:17
    at zone.js:1116:33
    at asyncGeneratorStep (asyncToGenerator.js:6:1)
    at _throw (asyncToGenerator.js:25:1)
    at _ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:368:26)
    at Object.onInvoke (core.mjs:11083:33)
    at _ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:367:52)
    at Zone.run (zone.js:129:43)
    at zone.js:1257:36
```

This is the axios.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import axios from 'axios';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AxiosService {

  constructor() { 
    axios.defaults.baseURL = "http://localhost:8080"
    axios.defaults.headers.post["Content-type"] = "application/json"

  }

  request(method: string, url: string, data:any): Promise<any>{
    return axios({
      method: method,
      url: url,
      data: data
    })
  }
}
```

I was hoping to click into the Login/Register button so I can get 200 code instead of 403 error code.

Comment: It depends on what the backend is doing. 403 most cases means that you are sending something wrong. It will be good to mention what is the exact response and what the backend is doing for the given endpoint

Comment: Thank you so much for your pointer! I managed to get it to return 200 code. The issue was in my AuthController, I had commented out the response implementation and was returning null Response. I did that previously so as to compile but had forgotten to uncomment it
```
@PostMapping("/register")
    public ResponseEntity<UserDTO> register(@RequestBody SignUpDto signUpDto)
    {
        return new ResponseEntity<UserDTO>(null);
        // UserDTO user = userServiceImpl.register(signUpDto);
        // return ResponseEntity.created(URI.create("/users/" + user.getId())).body(user);
    }```

Comment: As a side note/question; why use Axios as a 3rd party import instead of the dedicated, built-in Angular HttpClient?

Comment: @Krenom Since I am still learning, I just followed the youtube tutorial. At the time of video upload, it was his first time using Angular so he chose something familiar which was Axios. In his comments, he said it is better to use built-in Angular HttpClient. I should probably learn to change the Axios to HttpClient